# setting destinationviewcontroller's label's text in prepareForSegue throws error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am sure the string is not nil and that the label exists, I am trying to find out why the text in the label is nil. The other members of the destinationViewController are getting set correctly , but as soon as I add the line to set the label the program crashes.

```
// Mark segue
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
    var detailImages: Array<UIImage> = []
    detailImages.append(UIImage(named: "pup.jpg")!)
    detailImages.append(UIImage(named: "dog.png")!)
    // Set the property to the selected location so when the view for
    // detail view controller loads, it can access that property to get the feeditem obj
    detailVC.selectedLocation = _selectedLocation;
    println(_str!)
    detailVC.myLabel.text = "hello"
}
```

Comment: just change to `detailVC.myLabel?.text = "hello"`

Comment: doing `detailVC.myLabel?.text = "hello"` won't cause crash, but the text will not get set in `myLabel`.

Comment: Akhilrajtr is right, it didn't work with detailVC.myLabel?.text = "hello"  , i'm new here , why is my question -1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the outlet for `myLabel` will not get set in `prepareForSegue`, so it will be nil. Try below approach instead,

create a string var in `DetailViewController` like,

```
var labelText: String?
```

in `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
    var detailImages: Array<UIImage> = []
    detailImages.append(UIImage(named: "pup.jpg")!)
    detailImages.append(UIImage(named: "dog.png")!)
    // Set the property to the selected location so when the view for
    // detail view controller loads, it can access that property to get the feeditem obj
    detailVC.selectedLocation = _selectedLocation;
    println(_str!)
    detailVC.labelText = "hello"
}
```

and in viewDidLoad of `DetailViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myLabel.text = labelText
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the end I changed the last line in prepareForSegue to

```
detailVC.myString = _str as? String
```

I am not sure if I the the as? since in my detailVC I have added:

```
var myString:String?
```

Where would be the best place to convert the NSString to String, or it doesn't matter?
Thanks!