# Navigation Bar Not Showing on Embedded TableViewController - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios10, xcode8

I have a NavigationController embedded in my TableViewController. When I run the app everything works fine, but the Navigation Bar does not show.

This is how my code looks:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let box = boxes[indexPath.row]
    print(box.name)



    if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BoxDescriptionTVC") as! BoxDescriptionTableViewController
        self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        viewController.boxDetailsLabel.text = box.boxDescription
        if let boxImageURL = box.boxImageURL {
            viewController.boxImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: boxImageURL)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I create an instance of my NavigationController to present it instead of the TableViewController?

Comment: you should create an Instance of your navigation controller and present it instead of BoxDescriptionTVC.

Comment: How do I create an instance of my NavigationController to present it instead of the TableViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can set storyboardID for NavigationController in your storyboard. Then, you can write code like as follows. 
(I assume that your viewcontrollers are located in "Main" storyboard and you can set storyboardID in the Identity inspector)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let boxDescriptionNavVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(BoxDescriptionNavID) as! UINavigationController
let destinationTableViewVC = boxDescriptionNavVC.topViewController as! YourTableViewVC
destinationTableViewVC.textVariable = box.boxDescription
presentViewController(boxDescriptionNavVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: got this from the console:                                                                          fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.            Its got triggered in this line:                                           viewController.boxDetailsLabel.text = box.boxDescription

Comment: what is your embedded navitationcontroller's Storyboard ID? Did you put that exact same ID in instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier function?

Comment: i put this: "BoxDescriptionNavID"

Comment: OK. I see. That error occurs because your boxDescriptionNavVC does not have an UILabel control. I will revise the answer soon.

Comment: Done. Hope it will sort out your problem

Comment: it is still breaking for some reason.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I am getting the data from firebase. I have tried passing just a string like "whatever" but it still crashes. Should I make class variables in my destination controller and assign the values to that?

Comment: I corrected my answer. Yes, you need to declare a variable which stores your passed value in your TableViewController and then you can save your passed value in UILabel text property. You can refer to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31283560/5657370)